# interfacing MATLAB and ClearSCADA

Tags: interface, matlab

Is it possible to pass data from Matlab to ClearSCADA software?

On their forums I found this:
http://telemetry.schneider-electric.com/id3/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=51&threadid=973 but this description is unclear to me.

Any experiences with interfacing Matlab/ClearSCADA ?

Answer (score 1):

So, I've solved this problem: ClearScada offers convenient .NET API.
Just load ClearScada.dll (can be found in CS installation dir) as a normal .NET assembly.